# Issue in Excel 365 64-bit, in the Find/Replace dialog, the "Find what" and "Replace with" dropdowns are not remembering prior entries

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cannot find this anywhere on Google.

I recently upgraded to the 64-bit version of Excel 365. In this version of the application (not the online version), I am seeing an issue with the Find/Replace dialog.

Specifically, the "Find what" and "Replace with" dropdowns are not remembering prior entries. I don't know precisely when this started, but I first noticed 2-3 weeks after the upgrade, and it is the only change I can think of that might be causative. I am running a macro that uses Selection.Replace for some of the more repeatable replacements, but the workbook I'm working on also has some ranges where it isn't safe to do this in bulk, and removing the macro doesn't seem to have any effect.

Anyone seen this before, and more importantly, figured out how to fix?

Comment: Please check the version number of your Office. My Office apps is Version 2018 (Build 14326. 20404), and I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Appreciate you getting back to me.  Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14228.20288) 64-bit.  I however found the issue, which was that one of my macros was mapped to the Ctrl+f shortcut, and was taking precedence over the normal shortcut to launch the Find/Replace dialog.  Most of the time I was launching the Find/Replace dialog with Ctrl+h because that was the most frequent operation I needed, so I didn't bump into this until I went digging.  I seem to recall that Excel used to warn you when you selected a keyboard shortcut that was going to overwrite some other shortcut. Thx again

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.  If your computer has a discrete graphics card, please check whether the shortcut keys of the discrete graphics card occupy "Ctrl+H".

Comment: Nvidia but I don't see any mapping to the Ctrl+H keystroke.  My issue cleared up after I removed the mapping of Ctrl+F to one of my macros, so I'm good now. Thanks again.